Trying to make simple 90 degree elbow pipe, having issue with Bridge Edge Loops
Goal: I want a 90 degree elbow pipe.
Issue: Bridge Edge Loops is responding differently than tutorials, not returning a 90 degree bend from surface to surface, and I don't understand why.
General: I am fairly new to blender. 


After performing the operation, look to the popup menu to the bottom left. Expand it and increase the number of cuts to get it to become an elbow.
On another note, I don't recommend you leaving the faces from your cylinder end caps in place prior to performing the bridge. You should almost certainly delete them before proceeding, or else you'll end up with non-manifold geometry, meaning that later rendering efforts could get glitchy.

"You should almost certainly delete them" Why bother to delete the faces? The Bridge Edge Loops tool removes them automatically so there is no non-manifold geometry afterwards... did you not notice that?

I did not. Thanks for explaining that.

As the other answer already explained, you have to increase the number of Cuts in Bridge Edge Loops tool, I do not know what they tell in the tutorials you were watching, but your screenshot shows 0 cuts and without you cannot build a smooth transition.
Speaking of smooth transitions: the Smoothness default value in the tool is 1, and below you can see what this looks like on the left compared to what I think 90° elbow pipes look like on the right.

Of course if the two pipe pieces are further apart, the bend might not be overlapping that much, but it will never look like the profile was really rotated by 90°. Therefore you have to adjust the Smoothness value to around 0.585 (a long time ago I tried to find a mathematically exact value but I do not know how Blender calculates this smoothness so I failed).

Nevertheless, the Bridge Edge Loops tool is good to get smooth transitions between edge loops even if they have different shapes. But depending on how you want or have to create the elbow pipes, maybe the Spin tool might be interesting for you as well.
Take the following example, this looks a bit complicated but only if you want to have specific defined dimensions of the pipe, which I am going to demonstrate.
I only have a piece of vertical pipe. In my case, I know the center of the top edge loop is at (0, 0, 1) and I want the pipe to continue after a 90° turn with the center at (0, 2, 3). Then I have to spin the top edge loop by 90° on the X axis around a pivot point at (0, 2, 1).

So what I do is activate the Spin tool, set a number of Steps of whatever number of segments I want and choose the X axis for spinning.

Because I want the pipe to continue to the right, I grab the right red circle with the Plus symbol and drag it to the right. This looks terrible at first, because the current position of the 3D Cursor is the pivot point, but that does not matter. You could hold the Ctrl key to rotate in 5° steps to ensure you get the 90° accurate, but for now that does not matter either.

It does not matter because after you release the spin however far you have dragged it by now, the tool options panel appears at the bottom left of the 3D Viewport. There you can set the Angle to 90° and Center XYZ i.e. the pivot point of the rotation to (0, 2, 1) just as needed (and you can still change the number of Steps there as well).

After spinning you can simply extrude the edge loop with the shortcut E in normal direction (if you have a closed face) or by pressing Y constrained to the Y axis (if you have an open edge loop).

This sounded more complicated then it is and is only necessary if you want well-defined positions for the pipe parts. Of course you could simply eyeball it until you have something you like by rotating it to the desired angle and then moving the Center either along the axes with the large arrows of the tool or freely by hovering your mouse over the yellow center ring so that it turns white, then grabbing and moving it:


For some reason, after getting some sleep and trying again, opening blender from scratch, it worked well. Your tutorial is incredible, I appreciate the time you have put into this post. You are the best!
